# get passed ID from an action

Tags: php, laravel, parameter-passing

In my blade I tried to pass the ID in an action link.

```
<a href="{{ action('DomainController@edit', $domain->id) }}">test</a>
```

I get the passed id like this in my controller:

```
public function edit()
    {
        $input = Input::get();
        dd($input);
    }
```

but the output of dd() is:

```
array:1 [▼
  5 => ""
]
```

But why is it an array? I only want the number but I don't see why laravel gives me the input as an array.

Comment: $segment1 = Request::segment(1); here is the reference http://laravel.io/forum/08-09-2014-get-url-segments-within-controller-index

Comment: well, this wasn't helpfull at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input::get()` gives you the whole input array. Use the specific key to get a specific value, for instance `Input::get('id')`. But your `action()` call appears to just append the id without a key. Try e.g. `action('DomainController@edit', ['id' => $domain->id])`.

That said, you may want to look at named routes and route model binding - makes the whole thing easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think that You should pass `$id` as a parameter in `edit`:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    dd($id);
}
```